# Better to store multiple values in a table column, or create new table?

Tags: mysql

I have a user table that stores data about the user. Let's say one of those things I need to store is about all the widget manufacturers that the user uses.  I need to get data about each of those manufacturers (from the manufacturers table) to present to the user. In the user table should I store the users manufacturers as multiple values in a column like below and then split it out to create my query?

#### user

```
id  | username  | password | widget_man_id | etc
1   | bob       | ****     | 1,4,3         | some data
2   | don       | *****    | 2,3,1         | some more data
.
.
```

Or should I create a new table that holds all users information about the manufacturers they use?  Like so...

#### user_man

```
id  | manufacturer  |  user  |  order
1   | 1             |  1     |  1
2   | 4             |  1     |  2
3   | 3             |  1     |  3 
4   | 2             |  2     |  1
5   | 3             |  2     |  2
6   | 1             |  2     |  3
.
.
```

and then perform a query like this for a given user...

```
select manufacturer, order from user_man where user=1
```

**ALSO, how could I sort the results in descending order based on the *order* field?

Comment: what is the result you want?

Comment: Cant you create foreign relationship table called manufacturers and in user table store id of manufacturer. Then you just need to join 2 tables

Comment: Please do not ever store data in a comma separated list in a column...A puppy dies everytime this is done.

Comment: try `FIND_IN_SET` if it can help you.

Comment: @AshReva  I am not familiar with foreign relationship tables, or joining tables.  Got an example?

Comment: @JW.  Not familiar with FIND_IN_SET.  Example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to implement here is a [Many-to-Many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship between your `Users` and `Manufacturers`.

The only good way to do this in most RDBMS, such as MySQL, is through a [Junction Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). Although it does not reflect a particular object of your model, it will help modeling the relationships between the two others.

Create a third table, and do not forget to create Foreign Keys so you can prevent errors while updating or inserting records, and use some interesting features such as cascade deletion.

Answer (score 5):

Do not put multiple values into a single column and then split them out.  This is much slower for querying as each of the values cannot be indexed.  You are much better off having a table with a separate record for each one.  You can index this table and your queries will run much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Separate table  is the only the way to go.

To order your results in descending order just add `DESC` keyword

```
SELECT manufacturer FROM user_man WHERE user=1 ORDER BY `order` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The common approach would be to have a table user (like yours but without the widget_man_id):

**user**

```
id  | username  | password | etc
1   | bob       | ****     | some data
2   | don       | *****    | some more data
```

A manufacturer table:

**manufacturer**

```
id  | name  | etc
1   | man1  | some data
2   | man2  | some more data
```

And a many-to-many relationship table (like your example):

**user_man**

```
id  | manufacturer  |  user  |  order
1   | 1             |  1     |  1
2   | 4             |  1     |  2
3   | 3             |  1     |  3 
4   | 2             |  2     |  1
5   | 3             |  2     |  2
6   | 1             |  2     |  3
```